# How would you refactor the repetitive 'for-of' loop

Tags: typescript, rxjs, refactoring

I do have this code:

```
  runA() {
    const request = [];
    for (const item of this.items ) {
      request.push(this.getRequestData(item.prop1)); // want to generalize that
    }

    return forkJoin(...request).pipe(x => x);
  }

  runB() {
    const request = [];
    for (const item of this.items ) {
      request.push(this.getOtherData(item.prop2)); // want to generalize that
    }

    return forkJoin(...request).pipe(x => x);
  }
```

I want to refactor that code so I be able to pass different things in to `request.push()` to avoid loop duplications. My `item` contains different properties so for some cases I need `item.prop1`, sometimes `item.prop2` So my final code should be looks like:

```
  run(param) {
    const request = [];
    for (const item of this.items ) {
      request.push(param); // need to get this right
    }

    return forkJoin(...request).pipe(x => x);
  }

  runA() {
    run(this.getRequestData(item.prop1)) // need to get this right
  }

  runB() {
    run(this.getOtherData(item.prop2)) // need to get this right
  }
```

Is there any way you can achieve that in typescirpt?

Answer (score 1):

This function should do what you want

```
getAllData(prop){
 return forkJoin(Object.keys(this.items).map(key=>this.getRequestData(this.items[key][prop])))
}
```

Comment: is there any way to achieve that just wit 'for-of' loop as it seems more clean to do it that way.

Comment: that you have already done in your code if you want to use for-of 
`run(param) {
    const request = [];
    for (const item of this.items ) {
      request.push(this.getRequestData(param)); // need to get this right
    }

    return forkJoin(...request).pipe(x => x);
  }` 
but you only missed turning request into observable part

Answer (score 0):

Your function does two things:

1. transform the items into request array.
2. Send all requests in that array.

Putting these two things into one function would make sense **if the function was doing the same thing every time** but part 1 in your function does different things on different calls, (prop1 vs prop2 and getRequestData vs getOtherData) so it doesn't make sense to put it inside the function.

To make this clear, suppose you left part 1 in, you might decide to send a selector function as a parameter, which would give you the following:

```
RunX((item) => {return getRequestData(item.prop1)});
RunX((item) => {return getOtherData(item.prop2)});
```

Which is just over complicating the following code:

```
let requests = this.items.map((item) => {return getRequestData(item.prop1)});
SubmitRequests(requests);
let requests = this.items.map((item) => {return getOtherData(item.prop2)});
SubmitRequests(requests);
```

If the processing logic actually repeats extract a method getProp1Requests();

If you decide to go down this path anyway, send a selector function:

RunX(selector: (Item) => RequestData){

}

But you probably **don't** want to use item[prop] as that would take away the type checking.

Answer (score 0):

Why just don't pass getter function as argument to `Run` function?

```
  runAll(getter: (field: string) => any, propName: string) {
    const request = [];
    for (const item of this.items ) {
      request.push(getter(propName));
    }
    return forkJoin(...request).pipe(x => x);
  }
```

Invoke with:

```
runAll(this.getRequestData, 'prop1Name')
runAll(this.getOtherData, 'prop2Name')
```

You can make it extra type-safe to ensure, that only valid `Item` key is passed:

```
runAll(getter: (field: string) => any, propName: keyof ItemClass)
```